# iOS Bluetooth Service

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

Im can't seem to find an answer to this question so I'm posting here.

Basically, I have a bluetooth device paired with an iPhone, and all users will have the same.

What I need is a way to create a "Service" such that when the device comes into range for a specific function to be executed. I only need the code to run once per day(preferably) and will only take a few seconds to finish, then I'm fine with my application being killed.

I find it hard to believe no one else has tried to do this. Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated.

I also need to do this on android, but Ill post a separate question after googleing for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to go about doing this using Core Bluetooth:

```
 1. Opt into Core Bluetooth's background modes

 2. Create a CBPeripheralManager with an identifier (for background mode) and implement all of the CBPeripheralManagerDelegate methods

 3. Once you receive the delegate callback peripheralManagerDidChangeState: and the state is CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn

     a. Create a CBMutableCharacteristic with an app-specific UUID (use the CBUUID class method UUIDWithString:).  You can generate a UUID in terminal using "uuidgen"

     b. Create a CBMutableService and set the characteristic (above) to the services's characteristic property

     c. In the CBPeripheralManagerDelegate peripheralManager:didAddService:error: method, publish the service with options passing a NSDictionary with a key-value pair being CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey:a_UUID where a_UUID is another UUID generated from terminal or the same UUID as the characteristic.

 4. Create a CBCentralManager with an identifier and implement all of the CBCentralManagerDelegate methods as well as all of the CBPeripheralDelegate methods.

 5. Once you receive the delegate callback centralManagerDidChangeState: and the state is CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn, Scan for peripherals that are advertising a service with the same UUID you used in step 3c.

 6. When you discover a peripheral

     a. Retain the peripheral any way you want and attempt to connect.

     b. Once you receive the CBCentralManagerDelegate centralManager:didConnectPeripheral: method

         i. Set yourself as the delegate of the peripheral

         ii. Discover the service you created in step 3b

         iii. Discover the characteristic you created in step 3a using the UUID you used in step 3a.

 7. At this point the two devices are able to communicate at the application layer, if you will.  You could read the value of the peripheral's characteristic and in the CBPeripheralManagerDelegate peripheralManager:didReceiveReadRequest: method execute the function you mention in your question.

 8. Cancel the connection from the peripheral.
```

**Note that an iOS + Android bluetooth connection will not work.

Comment: I do not require communication of Android<->iOS I did not expect that to work ... Quick question while I try to implement this, will this work with bluetooth devices that use the "ExternalAccessory.framework" lib? ... Just to confirm that this will work even after the application has been "killed" or removed from memory?

Comment: The EA framework doesn't have the same backgrounding support as CB but you could use both of the frameworks together.   I haven't used EA before but this page of the docs is probably a good place to start: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Articles/MonitoringEvents.html If the app is killed by the user (pressing the home button twice and then swiping up on the app preview) then your app will not receive any callbacks until the user opens the app again.

Comment: Im not very experienced with iOS,  I'll take a look at that article.  So what would be a major difference between doing this or using a background fetch timer that will just take up and check for the device? Both will be majorly limited by the fact the user can kill the app and then you can no longer execute.

Comment: Any timer you set will be killed by the system once your app is in the background.  You could schedule a local notification that prompts the user to open the app each day and then attempt to reconnect to the peripheral.  It is fine if the peripheral is not in range when the notification is opened because connection requests do not time out.